# How to hold method untill array has 2 elements in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mean

I want to hold the method until the array has 2 or more elements using nodejs and mongodb..

```
exports.Arrayelements = function(req, res) {
    var elementName = req.body.elementName;
    connection.arrayelements.updateMany({}, { $push: { sampleArray: [elementName] } }, { upsert: true });
    connection.arrayelements.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(docs[0].elementName.length >= 2) {
            // call this function
        } else {
            // want to call back again to push syntax until 2 or more elements in array
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I guess you need to poll, using `setInterval` or such

Comment: Thank you @Thilo, i will try. actually am new to node js and mongodb

Answer (score 0):

First of all [find](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find) returns a cursor, and if you need the first document only (docs[0]), it's either `connection.arrayelements.findOne({})` or `connection.arrayelements.find({}).next()`.

Next problem is both [updateMany](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#updateMany) and [next](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#next) accept callbacks or return promises. You don't use the promise returned by updateMany in your snippet and it is an error. Your find statement may return results before the update happened, subject to race conditions.

Lastly, using setInterval is rather ill-advised. If you need to repeat `updateMany` statements in a loop until the result of find matches your criteria - just do it. With async/await syntax it is as simple as this:

```
exports.Arrayelements = async function(req, res) {
    const elementName = req.body.elementName;
    do {
        await connection.arrayelements.updateMany({}, { $push: { sampleArray: [elementName] } }, { upsert: true });
        const doc = await connection.arrayelements.findOne({});
    } while(doc.elementName.length >= 2);
    // call this function
}
```